# Ember.js - Error while loading route: TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined

Tags: rest, ember.js, ember-data, relationships

I'm getting the following error in my Ember.js app.

```
    Error while processing route: books Cannot set property 'store' of undefined TypeError: Cannot set property 'store' of undefined
    at DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.modelFor (http://localhost:8080/js/libs/ember-data.js:2986:19)
    at DS.Store.Ember.Object.extend.recordForId (http://localhost:8080/js/libs/ember-data.js:2437:17)
    at deserializeRecordId (http://localhost:8080/js/libs/ember-data.js:3355:23)
    at deserializeRecordIds (http://localhost:8080/js/libs/ember-data.js:3369:5)
    at http://localhost:8080/js/libs/ember-data.js:3335:7
    at http://localhost:8080/js/libs/ember-data.js:7117:16
    at http://localhost:8080/js/libs/ember.js:14899:20
    at Object.OrderedSet.forEach (http://localhost:8080/js/libs/ember.js:14741:14)
    at Object.Map.forEach (http://localhost:8080/js/libs/ember.js:14897:14)
    at Function.DS.Model.reopenClass.eachRelationship (http://localhost:8080/js/libs/ember-data.js:7116:38)
```

I'm using

- ember.js version 1.7.1 and
- ember-data.js version 1.0.0-beta.5.

I have the following project:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.ApplicationAdapter = DS.RESTAdapter.extend({
    host: 'http://localhost:8080'
});


App.Router.map(function() {
    this.resource('books', { path: '/' });
});

App.BooksRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model: function() {
        return this.store.find('book');
    }
});


App.Author = DS.Model.extend({
    firstname: DS.attr('string'),
    lastname: DS.attr('string')
});

App.Book = DS.Model.extend({
    title: DS.attr('string'),
    authors: DS.hasMany('author')
});
```

and the following is my JSON response to `http://localhost:8080/books`.

```
{
   "books":
   [
       {
           "id": 0,
           "authors":
           [
               {
                   "id": 0,
                   "firstname": "Andrzej",
                   "lastname": "Sapkowski"
               }
           ],
           "title": "Zaklínač I: Poslední přání"
        },
        ...
   ]
}
```

When I remove the `Author` model and the `authors` relationship declaration, the application works fine.

The error message I'm getting doesn't reveal the cause and according to what I've found on the Internet, my code seems to be ok.

What's the problem?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace of the error message, as well as the versions of Ember and Ember-Data you're using?

Comment: I upgraded ember.js to 1.7.1, but I'm still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow, I can't believe I didn't notice this, but your data isn't formatted properly. It should look something like this:

```
{
    "books": [{}, {}, {}],
    "authors": [{}, {}, {}]
}
```

This is explained in the [REST adapter guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/models/the-rest-adapter/#toc_sideloaded-relationships).